# JUnit test case for Java Runnable run

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, mockito, runnable

I want my program to run fine even though there is an exception. The following does that. Can someone help me writing JUnit test case for this?

```
protected static Runnable myMethod=new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //my code - may raise exception
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            logger.error("Exception occured", t.getMessage());
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Throwing an exception up from a `@Test` method will cause it to end with an error, which isn't a success. So the textbook approach for such cases is to just set up the conditions, run the method, and assume everything is OK if an exception doesn't cause the test to error:

```
@Test
public void testMyLogic() {
    // Set up conditions that would cause an the Runnable's body to throw an exception
    myMethod.run();

    // If we got here an exception was NOT thrown.
    // Implicitly, we're OK.
}
```